# PhpStorm Xdebug Symfony configuration

Tags: symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm struggling with the topic configuration

Following this guide: https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/blog/step-by-step-debugging-with-xdebug-symfony-and-phpstorm

I've installed the XDEBUG

```
PHP 7.4.13 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2020 06:24:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

[image]

This is my xdebug config

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebub.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_mode = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

And installed the [xdebug extension in chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc)

I've put some BreakPoint in a controller to check if it works.. nothing happens

If i try to validate the debug server config this is the error

[image]

I think because of the security config in symfony but i've also "opened" the accesso to a subfolder (public/test) without success

Can someone help me with this configuration?
Thanks

**[EDIT]**

As suggested by @LazyOne i removed the row with typo in xdebug config

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log=/media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/xdebug.log
```

I've tried also to modify the index.php in public folder adding

```php
if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli-server') {
    // To help the built-in PHP dev server, check if the request was actually for
    // something which should probably be served as a static file
    $file = __DIR__ . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if (is_file($file)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

as suggested in [phpstorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/validating-the-configuration-of-the-debugging-engine.html#check-web-path-to-validation-script-correctly-configured), in order to validate configuration of debugger, but the result is a blank web page (public/test.php -> echo "test").

**[EDIT 2]**
This is my XDEBUG Config printed from phpinfo

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

[image]

**[EDIT 3]**
I've addedd `xdebug.idekey=*PHPSTORM*` to xdebug config, but the script stops at every request multiple times if there's no BP.
This is a complete log of XDEBUG to the page requested until i've reached the first BP

```
[38952] Log opened at 2020-12-17 13:46:02.963623
[38952] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[38952] [Step Debug] INFO: Connected to debugging client: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port). :-)
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///home/leandro/.symfony/php/7156db8ed3dfc7f503f23103615bf450f5f1947e-router.php" language="PHP" xdebug:language_version="7.4.13" protocol_version="1.0" appid="38952" idekey="PHPSTORM"><engine version="3.0.1"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[https://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2020 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 1 -n show_hidden -v 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="1" feature="show_hidden" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 2 -n max_depth -v 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="2" feature="max_depth" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 3 -n max_children -v 100
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="3" feature="max_children" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 4 -n extended_properties -v 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="4" feature="extended_properties" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 5 -n notify_ok -v 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="5" feature="notify_ok" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- feature_set -i 6 -n resolved_breakpoints -v 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="feature_set" transaction_id="6" feature="resolved_breakpoints" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- stdout -i 7 -c 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stdout" transaction_id="7" success="1"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- status -i 8
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="status" transaction_id="8" status="starting" reason="ok"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- step_into -i 9
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_into" transaction_id="9" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///home/leandro/.symfony/php/7156db8ed3dfc7f503f23103615bf450f5f1947e-router.php" lineno="12"></xdebug:message></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 10 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1BIUF9JREVfQ09ORklHJ10p
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="10"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[0]]></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 11 -- aXNzZXQoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="11"><property type="bool"><![CDATA[1]]></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 12 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9OQU1FJ10p
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="12"><property type="string" size="9" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MTI3LjAuMC4x]]></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 13 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1NFUlZFUl9QT1JUJ10p
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="13"><property type="string" size="5" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[MzU5MDM=]]></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 14 -- KHN0cmluZykoJF9TRVJWRVJbJ1JFUVVFU1RfVVJJJ10p
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="14"><property type="string" size="44" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[L3JlY3VwZXJvY3JlZGl0aS9yYXRlaXp6YXppb25pL2dldC9yYXRlb2RhdGE=]]></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 15 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 445
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="15" id="389520386" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 16 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 473
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="16" id="389520387" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 17 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 409
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="17" id="389520388" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 18 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 420
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="18" id="389520389" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 19 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 430
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="19" id="389520390" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 20 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 443
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="20" id="389520391" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 21 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 483
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="21" id="389520392" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 22 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 482
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="22" id="389520393" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 23 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 411
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="23" id="389520394" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 24 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 452
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="24" id="389520395" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 25 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 459
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="25" id="389520396" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 26 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 478
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="26" id="389520397" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 27 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 426
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="27" id="389520398" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 28 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 476
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="28" id="389520399" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 29 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 416
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="29" id="389520400" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 30 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 460
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="30" id="389520401" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 31 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 418
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="31" id="389520402" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 32 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 439
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="32" id="389520403" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 33 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 484
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="33" id="389520404" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 34 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 422
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="34" id="389520405" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 35 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 475
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="35" id="389520406" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 36 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 480
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="36" id="389520407" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 37 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 406
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="37" id="389520408" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 38 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 448
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="38" id="389520409" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 39 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 454
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="39" id="389520410" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 40 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 467
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="40" id="389520411" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 41 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 438
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="41" id="389520412" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 42 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 456
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="42" id="389520413" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 43 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 428
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="43" id="389520414" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 44 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 413
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="44" id="389520415" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 45 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 415
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="45" id="389520416" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 46 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 464
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="46" id="389520417" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 47 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 470
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="47" id="389520418" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 48 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 433
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="48" id="389520419" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- breakpoint_set -i 49 -t line -f file:///media/leandro/Elements/Progetti/s4fgel/src/Model/FintelUtility/Rateizzazione/Manager/RateizzazioneManager.php -n 434
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="breakpoint_set" transaction_id="49" id="389520420" resolved="unresolved"></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 50
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="50"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///home/leandro/.symfony/php/7156db8ed3dfc7f503f23103615bf450f5f1947e-router.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- stack_get -i 51
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="stack_get" transaction_id="51"><stack where="{main}" level="0" type="file" filename="file:///home/leandro/.symfony/php/7156db8ed3dfc7f503f23103615bf450f5f1947e-router.php" lineno="12"></stack></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- context_names -i 52
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_names" transaction_id="52"><context name="Locals" id="0"></context><context name="Superglobals" id="1"></context><context name="User defined constants" id="2"></context></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 53 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzZiYjY5Y2NmLTBmMjEtNDY5Zi1hNGZhLWJhODBhNzM4MzAxYSddPSR0aGlzLT5pYU1Q
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="53" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 54 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJ2VmMTRjODFkLWEwYjQtNDZmMy04NThjLTRiYjQ3NzkxY2JlOSddPSRmYXR0dXJhRmdkLT5nZXRJbXBvcnRvQXBlcnRvTWF0ZXJpYVByaW1hUmVhbGUoKQ==
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="54" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 55 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJ2M0MGFkMmM1LTAwZDMtNDc5MC04MmM5LTJiZTQ0NDJmMzBjNSddPSRpbXBvcnRvUmF0YUNvbnN1bWF0bw==
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="55"><property type="null"></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 56 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJ2Y4ZTJmMjk4LTZlZmMtNDkxNC05MmRiLWMwMWNmMGFhOTAxMSddPSRpbXBvcnRvUmF0YQ==
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="56"><property type="null"></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 57 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzhlOTI2MzQ3LTBjZTYtNDhiMS1hN2JjLWFmNTFlMGYxYjMxMCddPSR0aGlzLT5pYUNS
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="57" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 58 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzIxZjZlODdkLTRhNjktNDQ0ZS1hZjQ0LTNlMjVhNDVlODU4ZSddPSRpbnRlcmVzc2k=
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="58"><property type="null"></property></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- eval -i 59 -- JEdMT0JBTFNbJ0lERV9FVkFMX0NBQ0hFJ11bJzAyMDE5NWIxLTRlOWUtNGMxZi04MmMwLTdiMDJiZTU0ODNhMCddPSRyYXRhLT5nZXRJbnRlcmVzc2koKQ==
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="eval" transaction_id="59" status="break" reason="ok"><error code="206"><message><![CDATA[error evaluating code]]></message></error></response>

[38952] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 60 -d 0 -c 0
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="60" context="0"><property name="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE" fullname="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE" type="array" children="1" numchildren="3" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="c40ad2c5-00d3-4790-82c9-2be4442f30c5" fullname="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE[&quot;c40ad2c5-00d3-4790-82c9-2be4442f30c5&quot;]" type="null"></property><property name="f8e2f298-6efc-4914-92db-c01cf0aa9011" fullname="$IDE_EVAL_CACHE[&quot
[38952] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 61 -d 0 -c 1
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="61" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" children="1" numchildren="2" page="0" pagesize="100"><property name="XDEBUG_SESSION" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;XDEBUG_SESSION&quot;]" type="string" size="8" encoding="base64"><![CDATA[UEhQU1RPUk0=]]></property><property name="PHPSESSID" fullname="$_COOKIE[&quot;PHPSESSID&quot;]" type="string" size="26" enc
[38952] [Step Debug] <- context_get -i 62 -d 0 -c 2
[38952] [Step Debug] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="62" context="2"></response>
```

Comment: 1) `xdebub.remote_enable=1` -- that's Xdebug v2 param. v3 will complain when it will see it. But then -- you have a typo there .. so it will be ignored. 2) *"If i try to validate the debug server config this is the error"* Check the web server access log to see what URL was requested and then check your app if it allows such URL (e.g. maybe you deny all URLs that are actual .php scripts (e.g. `/validate.php`)

Comment: 3) Show `xdebug_info()` output (captured in the same way as you are trying to debug: a CLI or web page). This is to check that expected config matches actual. 4) Enable Xdebug log and try to debug. Then see/share the log -- it will tell where it tries to connect to and what the response is etc.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks, about the first comment i've added an EDIT to my post

Comment: @LazyOne the xdebug  log is empty :(

Comment: 1) Your Xdebug settings (screenshots) show that `xdebug.log` is empty -- did you restart PHP/server after that? 2) It's possible that you/whatever do not send any "debug me" Xdebug flags. Try with `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` option (will try to debug every single request regardless of "debug me" flag). You need Xdebug log.

Comment: @LazyOne sorry, that was an old image, i'm updating with the new one (the file xdeug.log was created)

Comment: @LazyOne `xdebug.start_with_request = yes` this was the trick! Thank you... but how can i configure the "start" only with "debug"?

Comment: Sounds like you are not using your browser's Xdebug extension properly. I mean -- Xdebug does not see the "debug me" cookie. That's if you initiating the debug session from the browser.

Comment: Try checking https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html again. If nothing -- some small screencast may help clearing up what you may be missing (as it's hard to guess; it's much more easier to spot such nuances with own eyes). P.S. We could do some quick TeamViewer session if you wish...

Comment: @LazyOne i've added `xdebug.idekey=*PHPSTORM*` to my xdebug config and now it seems to start without forcing it... The problem is that i cannot avoid symfony to break at first line of the very first script everytime i make a request. Something  about https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#no-mappings

Comment: Check your path mappings then: what script Xdebug breaks on? what path Xdebug log shows for that script? What is the local path for that script seen in the IDE? (P.S. Any symbolic link will require path mapping, even if it's all local)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226095/discussion-between-jack-skeletron-and-lazyone).

Answer (score 11):

Ok finally i've found that with `symfony server:start` the client creates a temporary router inside the `/home/user/.symfony/php` folder (user is a "convention" here)
This means that in PhpStorm you must enable the "Break at first line in PHP scripts" option under "External connection"

[image]

This is because the router created is external relative to the project.

No mapping workaround is working.

There's an [issue opened here](https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/45)

So i temporary found that it all works if you start a local php built in webserver, so

```
cd /path/to/symfony_project/pulic
php -S localhost:8000
```

Here the complete procedure for `php v7.4` and `Symfony 5.2`:

---

**1 - Install XDEBUG**

In my case it installs XDEBUG v3.0.1

```
sudo apt install xdebug
```

Check if installed with `php -v`

---

**2 - Configure XDEBUG**
Locate your xdebug.ini, in my case is in `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/xdebug.ini` and configure with

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote = debug
xdebug.client_port = 9003
# It can be overridden with parameters but in default mode i want this using only PHPSTORM
xdebug.idekey=*PHPSTORM*
# Optional if you want a log
# xdebug.log=/path/to/xdebug.log
```

---

**3 - Install a browser extension**
Check [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/step_debug) the extension fo your browser.
Right click on the extension and set the Ide Key to PHPSTORM, then click to "Debug".

[image]

---

**4 - Start your local webserver**
As i said i used the built in php server so

```
cd /path/to/symfony_project/pulic
php -S localhost:8000
```

---

**5 - Check configuration with Phpstorm**

In the IDE *Run > Web Server Debug Validation*

[image]

First parameter should be the path to your public folder, then click *Validate*.

---

**6 - Start to debug**

That's it, place some Break Points and then start to debug your application

Comment: Re: path mapping though: we have tried adding it as an external library. We should have tried some another way as well. You have it working already anyway so its up to you, but checking this should not take much time. 1) Remove that extra entry from "PHP | Includes"; 2) Add at "Directories" using "Add Content Root" button instead (the same path). 3) Launch Symfony's web server 4) Hit "Reload from disk" in PhpStorm so it check for new files -- it should detect the newly created router file. 5) Try to debug.

Comment: The idea is: IDE does not seem to treat paths from "PHP | Includes" as a belonging to project (at very least for debugging entry point; which makes sense now that you think about it on how it works for other stuff like TODO, running inspections etc), so making that folder an actual part of the project should help (the project itself is an Content Root; and here we just add another root). Obviously, try that on a few pages, not just 1 page.

Comment: @LazyOne i'll  try as soon i'll fix the problem that made me to set up the debugger system :D

Comment: I think I did everything. I have the browser extension and enabled it for the specific tab, I have the "break on first line" in PHPStorm I have the same PHP and Symfony version, the webserver debug validation shows only green checkmarks. But when I make a request through the browser nothing happens. One difference is that I am on Windows and I needed to start the server through symfony server:start instead of php -S because that just gives me "The requested resource was not found on this server". Is this relevant do you think or is there anything else I might have forgotten?

Comment: Just seen I also have XDebug 2.8.1 but it worked just fine with Symfony 4.4 and using bin/console to start the server.

Comment: Thanks for the native PHP server hint: it did the job, maybe some bugs with the symfony server as debugging works both in bin/console and native php server

Answer (score 0):

You can look through this blog try to find solution: https://5minuteshack.blogspot.com/2022/08/xdebug-phpstorm-and-docker-why-it-not.html

In my case, it related to the bug of xdebug and phpstorm, and i have to follow this instruction to fix my issue: **PHP | Debug please disable Enable 'toString' object view.**