# Xdebug is having trouble running on WSL Symfony server using PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xdebug

I'm running a Symfony server with PHP7.3.33 & Xdebug 3.1.5 on a Debian Windows Sub-System Linux. I use PhpStorm on my Windows to code and I wanted to also use it to debug with Xdebug.

I had trouble to configure my Xdebug on my server but I managed to make it recognised by PhpStorm.

[image]

Then when I make a call to my server by loading a page, it stop on multiple files but not on my breakpoints. It also display me this error.

```
Cannot find a local copy of the file on the server /home/pierrem/.symfony5/php/4cddbar1067c22542bca91af1a7693a48ce69eea-router.php
Local path is //home/pierrem/.symfony5/php/4cddbar1067c22542bca91af1a7693a48ce69eea-router.php
```

[image: The error I get on my PhpStorm]

I've tried to fix this issue by opening the project from
`\\wsl$\Debian\home\XXXX` and `W:\home\XXXX` but it changed nothing.

EDIT: I started the server using php -S localhost:8000 and the debugger is working but only in my index.

When i try to put a breakpoint on my controller, it will display with an error and no stop on this breakpoint:

```
File path is not mapped to any file path on server. Edit path mapping to fix the problem.
```

I tryed to update my PhpStorm servers config as follow but this is still not working.

[image]

Comment: [Please add the error message as text, not just an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the issue is with the dynamically generated `***-router.php` file that Symfony creates -- when IDE gets the incoming debug connection it does not see that file in its' VFS (Virtual File System). I have seen this even if you would run the same on a local system. The issue will go away if you use a "proper" web server (Apache/nginx etc)

Comment: Even though ... you should still be able to stop at the breakpoints in controllers. Try hitting the Refresh button (`File | Reload all from Disk`) once you get this to see if the IDE will see that file there (unless it's in the Excluded folder, of course)

Comment: @LazyOne I added the access rights to my temp php folder for my windows and tryed to reload all from Disk but it changed nothing, I'm still unable to break to my breakpoints.

Comment: Such a file `***-router.php` seems to be generated on request / every time you make a change in your code. When the request comes in and you see that popup (on 2st screenshot), the IDE does not see that file (it shows no file option, only `neocampus` project). I'm not sure how it can be solved if the IDE does not do automatic "refresh" at that moment. I just know that using proper web server resolves that issue (as the request is not handled by Symfony's server then)

Comment: See this question and how the guy solved it. He had the same issue -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65326808/phpstorm-xdebug-symfony-configuration. It's about this `***-router.php` temp file that makes the whole thing to fail. Maybe you can disable creating them somehow (not using Symfony myself so cannot advise)

Comment: @LazyOne This is better but still not working on my controller. I updated the question.

Comment: You last screenshot does not make any sense to me: the `host` should be just host name, not the port. The path mappings is the same - makes no sense to me. I may only suggest to delete ALL entries there, try to debug and let the IDE create one for you (will be done from that dialog that popups on the 1st screenshot). **TBH** I do not think it can be solved here (as per my link earlier). Not sure at all.

Comment: I will try later, but for the "host", it was already written like this, i just changed the path on this window.

Comment: Symfony server creates a temporary router inside the /home/user/.symfony/php, that's why you're having the first error message. Try to follow the steps here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65353702/5391965

Comment: I suggest unchecking "Use path mapping" and here's how to fill the Debug server FYI https://i.imgur.com/JrXxJ8W.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne and @Reynadan who helped me to make it work.

First in my case I needed to start the server by using the following command inside my ***project_name/public*** folder.

```
php -S localhost:8000
```

Then in PhpStorm I go to "PHP > Servers" and remove all my config entries.

I started a debug session where the only breakpoints I could use where in my `index.php` file because PhpStorm where not able to see outside the folder where I started my server. I then go back to my Servers config in PhpStorm  (a new config app) and added an Absolute path for my project `/home/pierrem/neocampus` as follows (there where already the path of my `/public/` folder but it's not needed because it is inherited from the parent.)

[image: PhpStorm server config here]

Now I can put breakpoints in my controllers.

Comment: Nice one. Glad you have made it working. I though it could not be done (based on past experience). It looks now that there were certain changes made since then + it may have been done something wrong in the first place (like you starting PHP server in the wrong folder).

Comment: P.S. There is no need for a **separate** mapping for `public` -- it is in the same folder (both local and remote) and therefore will be inherited just fine from the parent. Separate mapping can only be needed when the path differs (e.g. a symlink used etc)